# How to serve multiple versions of model via standard tensorflow serving docker image?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm new to Tensorflow serving,

I just tried Tensorflow serving via docker with [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/docker) and succeeded.

However, when I tried it with multiple versions, it serves only the latest version.

Is it possible to do that? Or do I need to try something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to achieve this by building my own docker image which uses `--model_config_file` option instead of `--model_name` and `--model_base_path`.

So I'm running tensorflow serving with below command.

`docker run -p 8501:8501 -v {local_path_of_models.conf}:/models -t {docker_iamge_name}`

Of course, I wrote 'models.conf' for multiple models also.

**edit:**

Below is what I modified from original docker file.

original version:

`tensorflow_model_server --port=8500 --rest_api_port=8501 \
--model_name=${MODEL_NAME} --model_base_path=${MODEL_BASE_PATH}/${MODEL_NAME} \`

modified version:

`tensorflow_model_server --port=8500 --rest_api_port=8501 \
--model_config_file=${MODEL_BASE_PATH}/models.conf \`

Comment: Any chance you could put an example setup somewhere? I am trying to achieve the same thing but I'm clearly passing the wrong thing to the docker image

Answer (score 6):

This require a ModelServerConfig, which will be supported by the next docker image tensorflow/serving release 1.11.0 (available since 5. Okt 2018). Until then, you can create your own docker image, or use tensorflow/serving:nightly or tensorflow/serving:1.11.0-rc0 as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52372813/10455493).
See that thread for how to implement multiple models.

If you on the other hand want to enable multiple versions of a single model, you can use the following config file called "models.config":

```
model_config_list: {
    config: {
        name: "my_model",
        base_path: "/models/my_model",
        model_platform: "tensorflow",
        model_version_policy: {
            all: {}
        }
    }
}
```

here "model_version_policy: {all:{ } }" make every versions of the model available.
Then run the docker:

```
docker run -p 8500:8500 8501:8501 \
    --mount type=bind,source=/path/to/my_model/,target=/models/my_model \
    --mount type=bind,source=/path/to/my/models.config,target=/models/models.config \
    -t tensorflow/serving:nightly --model_config_file=/models/models.config
```

**Edit:**
Now that version 1.11.0 is available, you can start by pulling the new image:

```
docker pull tensorflow/serving
```

Then run the docker image as above, using tensorflow/serving instead of tensorflow/serving:nightly.